# Django project structure with multiple apps

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I intend to make a django project with multiple apps. The main folder shall have a base.html which shall have links to different apps. The apps will have their own template directory.

```
-myproject
    -__init__.py
    -settings.py
    -views.py
    -urls.py
    -admin.py
    -test.py

-app1
    -templates
        -abc.html
    -views.py
    -urls.py

-app2
    -templates
        -abc2.html
    -views.py
    -urls.py
```

What are the configuration I should make in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

Sandesh, Welcome to StackOverflow.

You should include the URLs from your apps in `myprojects/urls.py` like this:

```
[path('', include('app1.urls')),]
```

And `app1/urls.py`:

```
path('app1/', views.index)
```

Then on `app1/views.py`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Having this structure would be enough to make those apps run in separate URLs. Then you can create a landing app which would have a `base.html` and has links to those apps.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple apps and was seeking the same question, but I was having trouble getting to my default index page of the "catalog" app even with the answer.

I my project is setup different and looks like this:

- kbbn (project)

  - kbbn (package)
  - templates

    - kbbn (home html pages: index, about, contacts, layout.html etc...)
    - registration (login, register, etc...)
  - static

    - kbbn (content, fonts, scripts)
- app (misc app for the default site)
- catalog (app for books and documents)

  - templates (home page: index.html)

    - catalog (other html pages)

I had to add the **argument: name**, path('catalog/', views.index, **name='catalog'**), because my layout.html for the whole site is in the project root templates folder and my navbar, href="{% url 'catalog' %}" was not finding the path.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the base template in your app templates. For example in abc.html and abc2.html :

```
{% extends 'myproject/base.html' %}
```